# Python variables that point to other variables

Tags: python, list, pointers, variables

Can i have a variable that basically returns another?

```
class person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.happy_face = faces[happy]
        self.angry_face = faces[angry]
        self.face = self.happy_face
    def draw(self):
        self.face.render()
    def upset(self):
        self.face = self.angry_face
    def calm(self):
        self.face = self.happy_face
```

so imagine that this person gets punched in the face, so a bruise is added to all the faces, then because it was punched, it calls upset, and now draws the bruised angry face. this all works well with normal assignment, but now imagine that a neutral action like putting on glasses occurs, now happy_face and angry_face have both changed, but draw() won't draw the glasses because self.face never changed. I am imagining some kind of way to make the code like this:

```
class person():
    def __init__(self):
        self.happy_face = faces[happy]
        self.angry_face = faces[angry]
        self.face = point(self.happy_face)
    def draw(self):
        self.face.render()
    def upset(self):
        self.face = point(self.angry_face)
    def calm(self):
        self.face = point(self.happy_face)
```

I know this isn't completely dumb because python lists do this exact thing:

```
wallet = ["card", "coin", "note", "ID"]
inHand = wallet
print(inHand)
wallet.pop()
print(inHand)


>> ["card", "coin", "note", "ID"]
>> ["card", "coin", "note"]
```

Does anyone know a way to make things other than lists do this easily.

Edit: after a lot of experimenting, i can do it, but only if i create a class within that class, then i can change the contents of that class

Comment: You are not thinking about variables properly.  Remember that EVERYTHING in Python is an object, and names are just references to objects.  If three names refer to a single object, then changes to that object will be seen in all three names.  But if you assign a new object to one of the names, that doesn't change the other two.  You can do `self.face = self.happy_face`, and they both refer to the same object.  You don't need a "point" function.

Comment: I see, how would i structure my code so that i can change self.happy_face and still have that be pointed to by self.face

Comment: if i say that happy_face = something else, then the face no longer points, where happy _face points, i need a way to go like happy_face.changeto(something else), but that would require creating objects/classes within the person class, which is a level of depth i do not want for my crappy program.

Comment: Correct.  You could create a `Face` class that contains the image object.  Or, slimy, you could have all the face objects by lists with a single element.  Then you can change `self.happy_face[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding correctly (I suggest asking using a generic example instead of a more abstract example), but is all you need just to set self.face again after you make changes?

Also, you could simplify your two methods into one.

```
def update_face(self, face_input):
    self.face = face_input
```

So modify the self.happy_face and then call update_face() after with the new face as the argument.

Comment: its just that i want it to be very efficient, and be smaller in general, this was the workaround.